# how Windows choose the harddisk to be installed in multi-disk setup

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, installation, sata

I have an old computer with 4 hard-disks, as this:

Motherboard: ASUS Rampage III

- SATA 1: Samsung 250GB
- SATA 2: Maxtor 500GB
- SATA 3: WD 2000GB
- SATA 4: WD 2000GB
- and SATA 0: DVD

It was working fine for about two years, but it had some issues in last days, and I decided to make a clean install.

But I'm don't understanding some things during installation:

1. Hard disk sequence
2. System disk selected by Windows

> 1. Hard disk sequence

While using [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) I see:
/dev/sda1: Samsung 250GB (Label: Windows)
/dev/sdb1: Maxtor 500GB (Label: Personal)
/dev/sdc1: WD 2000GB (Label: MPx)
/dev/sdd1: WD 2000GB (Label: Projects)
/dev/sr0: DVD

While using [Mini XP from Hiren Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org) I see:
c: Personal
d: DVD
e: Windows
f: MPx
g: Projects

And, during Windows 8 installation:
drive 0: MPx
drive 1: Windows
drive 2: Personal
drive 3: Projects

> 2. Boot partition selected by Windows

If I choose "drive 1: Windows" to install, and let installation run, after all, the disk marked as "system" is "drive 0: MPx". (I can see this with GParted Live)

After installation the letters assigned are:
Drive 1 - **C:** Windows
Drive 0 - **D:** Projects
Drive 2 - **E:** Personal
Drive 3 - **F:*** MPx
G: DVD

> What is happening ?
>
> How Windows choose the harddisk to be installed in multi-disk setup ?
>
> How Windows choose the hard-disk sequence to assign drive letters ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am asking the question "how Windows choose the harddisk to be installed in multi-disk setup", it is in the "title".

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post.  It is unfair to people who have taken the time to answer and it leaves a useless thread on the site.  If you are unable to delete your own post, flag a moderator and ask them to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You specifically choose the disk and partition where Windows installs.  It doesn't choose a random partition on a whim.